# Multiplying and Dividing two floating point numbers without using * and / operators

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve how to multiply and divide two numbers without using * and / operators

I tried using for loops:

```java
for(int a = 1; a<=secondnum; a++)
{
    total = firstnum + total;
}
cout << "Total: " << total;
     
for(b = firstnum; b>=secondnum; b = b-secondnum)
{
    total = total + 1;
}
cout << "Answer: " << total;
```

However this only works for integers...Is there a way for this to work on floating point values?

Comment: This seems highly impractical. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In order to multiple by floating number, you need to learn how to divide without using division operator. Start with that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Multiplication_and_division

Comment: @Blaze apparently it is an exercise (self-inflicted or given). The question can be answered on it's face value without the need to ask *why*.

Comment: @genpfault has nothing to do with OPs question.

Comment: You might want to look into bit shifts.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Bit shift with floating point values is not as straightforward as bit shift with integer types.

Comment: @SergeyA that's right, but sometimes there's an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so it can't hurt to know what the code is for.

Comment: @SergeyA the second for loop is for Division however it does not work if the Numerator is lesser than the Denominator :((

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Okiiiiiii

Comment: Division can't be implemented in a loop like that. It's not as simple as multiplication. To divide you can subtract the divisor until you get a remainder, but then you need to perform division on that remainder as well.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux hmmmmm I think thats what I did without the remainder.

Comment: I can suggest a bit naive, if performance is not the key here, solution. You can figure out how much numbers are after decimal in both numbers.For example if you have A= 2.34 and B=0,113, x = 2, and y = 3 (number after decimal points)
now just do A* 10^x , B*10^3 and treat them as Integers, after that set the decimal point on right position using x and y information.

Answer (score 1):

In the old days (before pocket calculators and the like), logarithm tables were used to turn multiplication and division into a matter of addition and subtraction:

```
#include <cmath>

double Mult(double a, double b)
{
  return exp(log(a)+log(b));
}
double Div(double a, double b)
{
  return exp(log(a)-log(b));
}
```

Note this only works for positive numbers, but it is relatively easy to work with absolute values and then give the result the correct sign.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this back in high school. I wrote a program that could multiply or divide two arbitrarily-long floating point numbers. Basically, I did it the exact same way I would have done it through long multiplication/division.

I kept both values in arrays of decimal digits.

```
char firstValue[1024];
char secondValue[1024];
```

I don't remember if I kept them as ASCII or converted them. It was 40 years ago, after all.

Then I worked it out on paper. Multiply isn't hard, although admittedly I used the * operator to multiply two one-digit values. But you could implement an integerMultiply method.

If you can do it in long hand on paper, you can write an algorithm for it. But it's way too long for an answer here.